# How to figure out the html color of an Interface Builder Color

Tags: iphone

I need to take the neat IB Color I have chosen for my background, and figure out the html color code so I can call it in the css declarations in the UIWebView content NSString. Easy way of doing this?
http://screencast.com/t/M2E3MmI5Yj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the Tint box in interface builder (your colour).

Click on the RGB sliders. These will be in decimal format.

Convert each number to hexadecimal with Google.

For example with the query: 255 in hexadecimal.

The last two letters in this case FF is the color.

Your html color is:

#RRGGBB

Where R is for red, G for green and B for blue.

Comment: ah u are very smart :) do u know if Apple is ok with using non-web safe colors?

Comment: Yes you should be fine. Web-safe colors are outdated.

Comment: do u know by any chance how to remove the gray background that is shown when u scroll too much on the UIWebView?